# Publishing angular app on github enterprise pages not working

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I recently built a simple angular app and decided to publish on enterprise github pages. I used the following method:

```
cd App
npm install
ng build --prod
cd ../app-github-pages-repo
cp -R ../App/dist/app/* .
git commit -m "Added the app"
git push
```

Within the github settings I see the message

```
Your site is published at https://host/pages/orgname/
```

But when I try to access it, it resources are not downloaded and page is not coming up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed setting base-href for your app. It is essential since your app is not hosted at the root of the domain.

You can try to build the app as follows:

```
ng build --prod --base-href https://host/pages/orgname/
```

make sure the base-href actually points to where the root of the sources are And follow rest of your steps.